# Run a JavaScript function continuously repeating with a time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my first question, and I would appreciate you answering soon.

I would like code to repeat a function continuously...
I have tried some code but it hasn't worked.

I tried this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{
$('#more').load('exp1.php'); // SERIOUSLY!
});
</script>
```

I want to repeat this function after some interval. I have tried 
`setInterval()` and `setTimeout()`

But, I haven't received results.

Comment: What was your code when you tried both `set...`?

Comment: You should not continuously fire ajax requests. If you want live updates, use server push technologies.

Comment: @Bergi if you want to support more browsers continuous poll is the only choice. comets and push notifications aren't supported widely yet...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will repeat the task until you clear the interval (with clearTimeout(repater))

```
var repeater;

function doWork() {
 $('#more').load('exp1.php');
 repeater = setTimeout(doWork, 1000);
}

doWork();
```

Per OP's original condition:

> I want code that repeat function continuously...

Comment: This will trigger not just one repeating cycle, but many (indefinitely).

Comment: Yes, just like OP requested. Read his description again.

Comment: @HristoYankov You might want to consider changing `setInterval` to `setTimeout`

Comment: The `setTimeout` needs to be provided in a callback function if you really want to have a consistent interval.

Comment: @Christoph, depends on the context of the backend and what it's doing. But generally, yes, if he is expecting to load some data and only then pull again, you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this like

```
var myFunction = function() {
    $('#more').load('bla.php'); 
};

var timer =  setInterval(myFunction, 1000); // call every 1000 milliseconds
```

or

```
var timer = setTimeout(myFunction, 1000); // call every 1000 milliseconds

clearTimeout(timer); //To stop the function from being called forever
```

as @Christofer Eliasson  **For an Ajax-request, you would probably want to use a timeout instead of an interval**, an start the timeout again in the callback, to make sure that you don't stack calls if the server is taking more than 1 second to respond

**Good Read**

1. [MDN:window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)
2. [MDN:window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

Comment: For an Ajax-request, you would probably want to use a timeout instead of an interval, an start the timeout again in the callback, to make sure that you don't stack calls if the server is taking more than 1 second to respond.

Answer (score 2):

For an Ajax-request I would use a [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) instead of an interval, and start the timeout again in the callback of the ajax-request.

If you use an interval of say 1 second and your server takes more than one second to respond, you will start to stack calls with an interval, since the interval will call the function every second no matter what. With the timeout-in-callback approach instead, you wouldn't start the countdown until previous request has completed.

I'm using an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to trigger the first call to the function. Then when the load has completed, I use a timeout to call the function again after one second:

```
(function loadContent(){
    $('#more').load('exp1.php', function () {
       setTimeout(loadContent, 1000);
    });   
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing it out there:

```
function doRequest() {
$.ajax({
  url: 'exp1.php',
  timeout: 1000,
  success: function(data) {
    $('#more').html(data);
    doRequest();
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about some good ol' fashion recursion?

```
function getStuff() {
    $('#more').load('exp1.php', function() {
        getStuff();
    });
}

getStuff();​
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zn2rh/1/

Comment: There is no timeout, it will fire indefinitely with NO pause! `setTimeout` is a better choice.