# How stop setTimeout after 1 min which is repeating every 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[Here is Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13894802/7694859)

Following function is doing one thing. "repeating every 1 sec infinitely."

But I want this function repeat every x second just for 1 min. After 1 min, it should stop forever.

```
var repeater;

function doWork() {
 $('#more').load('exp1.php');
 repeater = setTimeout(doWork, 1000);
}

doWork();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to keep a counter that's incremented on every call, and call the recursive `setTimeout` only when that counter is below 60:

```
let count = 0;
function doWork() {
  $('#more').load('exp1.php');
  count++;
  if (count < 60) setTimeout(doWork, 1000);
}
doWork();
```

Note that there's no need for the `repeater` variable since you aren't using `clearTimeout` anywhere.

Or, using `setInterval` and `clearInterval`:

```
const interval = setInterval(doWork, 1000);
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(interval), 59500);
doWork();
```

Comment: Just a note that setTimeout() and setInterval() techniques like this are not too precise. Every interval will add a few extra microseconds and by the time the last call is made, it may drift a second or two. Most of the time, this is not too important, but this is worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass in a value to the setTimeout duration as a multiplier. Assuming the lifecycle of the function exists beyond this duration, it would simply increment the value passed in.

So, you would multiply 1000 by an integer that would increment inside the function itself. Starting from 1 and going to 60. Then wrap the instructions inside an if statement. If the value of the increment integer is less than 60, do work.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one,

```
var count = 60;

function doWork() {
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
      $('#more').load('exp1.php');
      count--;
      if (count ==0) clearInterval(interval);
  },1000);
}

doWork();
```